Azure AI Blob Storage Chunking
I want to upload my data to blob storage, but they are big documents so I will need to chunk them down. I am planning to use Microsoft's data preparation script (from this page Azure OpenAI On Your Data, script here: Prepare Data Locally)
I have just read about this aswell: Integrated data chunking and embedding in Azure AI Search what would be the best way or can I just use the data preparation script to add to my blob storage?

Both options you mentioned, using the data preparation script to upload data to blob storage and utilizing integrated data chunking and embedding in Azure AI Search, have their own advantages and best use cases.
Choosing the Best Approach:

If you require more control over the chunking process or have specific requirements for organizing your data within blob storage, using a data preparation script to upload chunks to blob storage may be the better option.

If you prioritize simplicity and integration, and your use case aligns well with the capabilities of Azure AI Search, integrated data chunking and embedding could be the way to go.


